# Nokia here maps api: infobubble marker icon

Tags: javascript, icons, markers, here-api

I'm using "Nokia Here Maps" API trying to change the standard mark icon with a tooltip. I tried to use the property `icon: url`, but the icons don't change.

Here is my ascriptive code:

```
marker = new InfoBubbleMarker(data.location.position,infoBubbles,"<font style='font-size:2em'>"+ name</font>",{ 
eventDelegationContainer: markersContainer,
brush: { color: "#1080dd" },
icon: "../images/icon.png",
text: (markersContainer.objects.getLength() + 1),
draggable: false
});

markersContainer.objects.add(marker);
```

How can I change the standard icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the `InfoBubbleMarker` class used in the [Extend Standard Marker with InfoBubble](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/information-bubbles/extend-marker-to-infobubblemarker.html) example in the [API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer). As the title of the example suggests, it is using **Standard Markers** rather than **Custom Markers**, so the base code will need to be altered to work with icons.

Alter line 110 from:

```
extend(InfoBubbleMarker, nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker);
```

to

```
extend(InfoBubbleMarker, nokia.maps.map.Marker);
```

and you create icon-based **Custom Markers** instead.

Replace `brush` and `text` in line 216 onwards:

```
eventDelegationContainer: markersContainer,
    brush: { color: "#1080dd" },
    text: (markersContainer.objects.getLength() + 1),
    draggable: true
```

With

```
 eventDelegationContainer: markersContainer,
        icon: "../path_to_icon/icon.png
        draggable: true
```

as well.

Personally I would just create a `Container`, and add a click listener to the `Container` instead as shown in the Infobubble on Marker click example on the [HERE Maps Community Pages](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#infobubble-on-marker-click). The Container could hold any clickable objects so would work with both `StandardMarker` pins and custom `Marker` icons.